# Splitting 1 column into 1 to 3 columns in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have been wrestling with some **code** for a personal project and have been hitting some `roadblocks`.

I have some restaurant data and there is a column for the table with information separated by **"/"**.

**For example :**  `4/1 means table 4, and first check at that table for the day.  10/A/2 means Table 10, the check was split into 2 or more checks (A, B, C, etc) and this is check 10/A, and turnover 2.`

Checks can also be togo orders which may be denoted by the name of the order.

For example, here are some possible orders:

**1/1

1/2

10/A/3

10/B/3

Togo

Bob Togo**

And I want to split them into `1 to 3 columns` that are organized by table (or Togo), `split, and turnover.`  Like so:

```
> check <- c("1/1", "1/2", "10/A/3", "10/B/3", "Togo", "Bob Togo")
> checknum <- seq(1:6)
> dat <- cbind(checknum,check)
> dat
     checknum check     
[1,] "1"      "1/1"     
[2,] "2"      "1/2"     
[3,] "3"      "10/A/3"  
[4,] "4"      "10/B/3"  
[5,] "5"      "Togo"    
[6,] "6"      "Bob Togo"
```

And Ideally I want them to look like this:

```
> Table <- c(1,1,10,10,"Togo","Bob Togo")
> Split <- c(NA,NA,"A","B",NA,NA)
> Turn <- c(1,2,3,3,NA,NA)
> Ideal <- cbind(checknum,Table,Split,Turn)
> Ideal
     checknum Table      Split Turn
[1,] "1"      "1"        NA    "1" 
[2,] "2"      "1"        NA    "2" 
[3,] "3"      "10"       "A"   "3" 
[4,] "4"      "10"       "B"   "3" 
[5,] "5"      "Togo"     NA    NA  
[6,] "6"      "Bob Togo" NA    NA
```

Where all columns are for a specific aspect of the check with NAs for missing values.

Numeric values can be left as factors because each acts as a factor more than an integer.  Ideally, the `"Bob Togo"` would  be renamed `"Togo"` as well so that all Togo orders share the same factor.

I know this is a bit at once, but I've been hitting roadblocks for over 2 weeks now and I feel I'm missing something simple.

I'm relatively new to `R`, so any addition explanation with your answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would try splitting on `/ `and using logic. If there is no `/ `assign it to `Table`. If there is one `/` and character assign the first to `Table` and the second to `Split`.  If it is numeric and numeric assign the first to `Table`, the second to `Turn`. If there are three, I would still specify the character/num logic to verify that they are going into the right columns. It seems like if there is only one, it always goes into `Table`. You should be able to use a loop to go through that column using `if`, `ifelse` and `else`. statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this with `tidyverse` by `mutate`ing the 'check' column using `str_replace` and then `separate` the 'check' into three columns

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
   mutate(check = str_replace(check, "^(\\d+)/(\\d+)$", "\\1/NA/\\2"))  %>%
   separate( check, into = c("Table", "Split", "Turn"), sep="/", convert = TRUE)
#   checknum    Table Split Turn
#1        1        1    NA    1
#2        2        1    NA    2
#3        3       10     A    3
#4        4       10     B    3
#5        5     Togo  <NA> <NA>
#6        6 Bob Togo  <NA> <NA>
```

NOTE 1: It is better to create a `data.frame` as initial dataset than a `matrix` to accommodeate different class of columns

NOTE 2:  `tidyverse` is a collection of packages.  So, when load, it loads all the packages coming from that bundle.  As @mt1022 suggested, we don't need to load the whole `tidyverse`, instead can load `dplyr` (`mutate`), `tidyr` (`separate`) and `stringr` (`str_replace`).

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(checknum,check, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: up vote. In addition, I think it should be noted where `str_replace` comes from.

Comment: Thank you, Akrun!

I just got around to testing it out with my full dataset and worked wonderfully after a few tweaks.  Cheers!